# Python-POS machine to generate bill and inventory management

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, inventory-management

I am new to python, I am doing a pos machine that can genarate the bill and inventory management for my school assignment . I had no idea why my input for the product id will only generate twice but not continuosly until the input is 0 for the payment. Other than that, why when the bill is print out there is no product name and the price will be zero only?

**this my item list**

```
all_products = [
    [1, "Razer Deathadder V2 Pro" , 100, 349.00], 
    [2, "Razer Viper Ultimate",  105, 419.00], 
    [3, "Razer Basilink Ultimate" , 35, 599.00], 
    [4, "Razer Viper mini", 295, 139.00], 
    [5, "Razer Deathadder X", 592, 76.90]
]
```

**function to generate bill**

```
def generate_bill(product, price, lst):
    print("-" * 40)
    print("\t\tRazer Mouse Shop")
    print("-" * 40)
    print("Bill:{} \tDate:{}".format(int(random.random()*100000), str(datetime.now())))
    print("Product name\t\tprice")
    print("-" * 40)
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        print("{}\t\tRM{}".format(j , item[-1]))
    print("-" * 40)
    print("\t\tTotal Bill Amount: {}".format(price))
```

**The code when i choose to generate bill**

```
elif choice == 2:
        display_all()
        print("Press 0 for payment")
        item_lst = []
        total_price = 0
        prod_id = int(input("Enter the Product ID: "))
        while prod_id != 0:
            prod_id = int(input("Enter the Product ID: "))
            for item in all_products:
                if item[0] == prod_id:
                    item_lst.append(item[0])
                    total_price = total_price + item[2]
                    if item[1] == 0:
                        print("Sorry we are out of stock")
                    else:
                        item[1] -= 1
                    
                member = input("Do you have membership(Y/N): ")
                if member == "Y":
                    total_price * 0.9
                    generate_bill(item, total_price, item_lst)
                    print("Thanks For shopping with Us")
                    sys.exit(0)
                else:
                    print("Continue Shopping")
```

**The output**

[image]

**click this [the whole code at here](https://github.com/KentOJL/fitlin/blob/main/Sales_mangament.py)**

I had tried to change the totalprice += item[2] to totalprice = totalprice + item[2] in the while loop there, remove the prodid = int(input("Enter the Product ID: ")) from the while loops. But the output just the same, totalprice = 0 and the input for the prod_id just come out one time, not continuosly until i input 0.

Comment: Have you walked through your program line by line, like the computer will?  You ask for a product id, then you enter the `while` loop, throw that product away, and ask for another.  You need to use something like `prod_id = 999` before the loop.  Next, your inner loop tries to go through every item in `all_products`, but after you check the first item, you IMMEDIATELY ask for the membership number and exit the program, without even checking the second item.  Everything starting with `member =` needs to be OUTSIDE of the while loop, so you only do it after the last item has been picked.

Comment: Also, inside `generate_bill`, you're using `item[-1]`.  What is `item`?  This function has never heard of that.  I assume you really want `lst[j]` there.

Comment: Err, this is unrelated, but  I'm pretty sure you wanted **Basilisk** instead of **Basilink** in your `all_products` list.

Comment: @AashvikT nah, i prefer to use Viper Ultimate

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks a lot, the item[-1] is i want is the price to print out, so at the i had do it with a new price_lst, not that lst[j].

Comment: Uh, I meant that 'Basilisk' was spelt wrong in your code : I think you misunderstood the meaning of what I'd written!